# On not counting initial energy in cyclotrons

Tags: energy, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, particle-accelerators

The formula for finding the final kinetic energy of a particle exiting a cyclotron is $2nqV$, where q's the charge, V the potential, and n the number of rotations.

If the particle starts from exactly between the dees, isn't there an additional $\frac{qv}{2}$ energy from the initial acceleration that drives it into one dee? Or is that energy neglected?

Why isn't it considered in the equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A schematic diagram](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/280722233_Regulating_the_performance_parameters_of_accelerated_particles/figures?lo=1) of a cyclotron.

[image: cyclotron]

Note the point where it says "charged particle", it is at rest within errors, which means no or very little kinetic energy, not given by the gap. Any kinetic energy will be due to the mechanism that introduces the charged particle into the cyclotron.